# Sign out firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Making a simple firebase auth app with react-native. Register/sign in works just fine, but I can't get the sign out to work properly.

```
loginUser = (email,password) => {
    try{
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
        console.log(user)
      })
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error.toString())

    }
  }

  signOutUser = () => firebase.auth.signOut();
```

The sign out button is easy as this:

```
<Button style={styles.button}
            full
            rounded
            onPress={() => this.signOutUser()}
>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your function to sign users out is called `signOutUser` but you call a function named `deleteAccount` when your button is pressed.
Try:

```
onPress={() => this.signOutUser()}
```

Also you may need to change the signOutUser function to:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Made the changes, and added consol.log("Signed out") to check. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is named `signOutUser` in your code, but your HTML is trying to call a function named `deleteAccount`.

If you have a different `deleteAccount` we'll need you to show us that too.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have `firebase.auth.signOut()` and `auth` here is a function, therefore it should've been `firebase.auth().signOut()`